# Defer parsing of JavaScript Magento2

Tags: magento2, javascript

Hello is possible to fix this issue?
I know that are external js.
[image]

Comment: Where it is being called. Add either defer or asynchronous as <script SRC="" defer/asynchronous>. It will solve your problem

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In which file i have to add this script?

Comment: Can you able to identify from where the external scripts are called?

Comment: It show after a few attempts on the contact page and in most forms. If I'm not mistaken. But I'm not sure.

Comment: Are you using any module for reCAPTCHA?

Comment: No! But I have a custom theme, bought from TemplateMonster. I didn't find a captcha options in theme options. Umh..

Comment: Which version of Magento are you using?

Comment: Magento 2.2 CE , is only enabled for backend https://imgur.com/kAMdpSr

Comment: Search for the script in the custom module for recaptcha

Comment: I found module-captcha in vendor folder. What could I do?

Comment: If your module is in production that module is not the cause. Try searching for grep -r "gstatic.com" app/ folder

Comment: Nothing found ! Umh..

Comment: Can you find from where does the js script load from?

Comment: this ? http://prntscr.com/n5y21c